# How to update macOS to version 11.2.3?

Tags: macos, software-update, big-sur

My MacBook Air '14 is on macOS 11.2.1:
[image]

I want to install the update to 11.2.3:
[image]

And then, after waiting hours for an extremly slow download to finish:
[image]

Twice! Not sure if it makes sense to try again.
Has anybody installed the update succesfully on a MacBook Air '14?
Is there anything I could do to raise my chance of success?

**Update:** Seems like all it needed was a third try. This time the update was installed.

Comment: I am experiencing a similar issue yet with App updates in the AppStore!

Comment: The dialog says that you may have problems with the Internet that are preventing updates from being downloaded. Is the problem also there with another network?

Comment: You don't want to do this.  Only 4gb of RAM?